# Java servlet in netbeans8 does not read sql string with db driver ucanaccess and database ms access

Tags: java, servlets

I am using netbeans8 with jdk7 .I am using db ms-access and driver to connect is UCANACCESS. I am working on java servlet. Now i have 2 servlets and 2 classes.First Servlet(searchperson) is the presentation layer that takes the input from the user and second servlet(showperson) takes the input and passes to the database class(persondao) to search the person from ms-access db and my second class(personinfo) takes the searched parameters and shows to user from 2nd servlet. My servlet and calss names are.1)Saerchpersonservlet,2)showpersonservlet 3)personDAO class, 4)Personinfo class. Below is the code.The problem is the cursor goes to db class(persondao) but is not reading the db  sql string.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class SearchPerson extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>"+
        "<html>"+
        "<head>"+

        "<title>Servlet SearchPerson</title>"+
        "</head>"+
        "<body>"+
            "<form action=http://localhost:8084/projectapp/showpersonservlet > "+
                "<h1> Please enter the name to search </h1>"+
            "<input type=text name=pname> <br>"+
             "<input type=submit value=searchperson> <br>"+
              "</form>"+
        //out.println("<h1>Servlet SearchPerson at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        "</body>"+
        "</html>"
        );

}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

//showpersonservlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class showpersonservlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("usman");

    String sName=request.getParameter("pname");
        out.println(sName);
        PersonDAO psName=new PersonDAO();
        PersonInfo pInfo=psName.searchPerson("USMAN");



        if (pInfo!=null) {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet showpersonservlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet showpersonservlet at " + pInfo.toString() +   "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }
        else{
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet showpersonservlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>   No result found  </h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }





}// end process request 

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

//PERSONINFO CLASS

```
public class PersonInfo {
    private String sName;
private String address;
private String phone;

public PersonInfo(String sName,String address,String phone){
    setName(sName);
    setAdress(address);
    setPhone(phone);
}

public void setName(String sName){
    this.sName=sName;
}

public String getName(){
    return(sName);
}

public void setAdress(String address){
    this.address=address;
}

public String getAdress(){
    return(address);
}

public void setPhone(String phone){
    this.phone=phone;
}

public String getPhone(){
    return(phone);
}

public String toString(){
    return " Name: "+getName()+" Address: "+getAdress()+" Phone: "+ getPhone(); 
}    
}// end of class person info
```

//PersonDAO class the db call

```
import java.sql.*;
public class PersonDAO {


public PersonInfo searchPerson(String sName){
    PersonInfo person=null;
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try{
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/java/personinfo.accdb";
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String sql= "select * from emp where name=?";
        pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        pstmt.setString(1, sName);
         rs=pstmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String name=rs.getString("NAME");
            String adress=rs.getString("ADDRESS");
            String phoneno=rs.getString("PHONENO");
            person=new PersonInfo(name,adress,phoneno);
        }// end of rs net

    } catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex+"  Error at db level  ");}
    finally{
    if(con!=null){
        try{
        con.close();
        }catch(Exception ec){}  
    }

    if(pstmt!=null){
        try{
        pstmt.close();
        }catch(Exception ec){}  
    }
    if(rs!=null){
        try{
            rs.close();
        }catch(Exception ec){}
    }
}// end of  FINALLY catch exception

    return person;
    }// end of search person
/*
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PersonDAO perProj= new PersonDAO();
            PersonInfo per=perProj.searchPerson("USMAN");
            System.out.println(per.toString());
}
*/
}// end of class person dao
```

Comment: What do you mean, "not reading db string?"  Write a unit test case for your DAO and test that w/o any of the servlet stuff.

Comment: If i call "personDAO" class invidually without servlet, In a main method the database class "personDAO" works well. but if i call it from servlet the cursor goes into class "personDAO" and reads driver manager class and after this it leaves "personDAO" class without any exception or giving anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a deadlock. It's due of your to an improper use of the updatable ResultSet.

To replace

```
pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

with

```
pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

might solve the issue.